# Issues with linux mint installation on vmware player

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint, iso-image, vmware-player

I downloaded the iso image of Linux mint 17.1 cinnamon and then burned it to a dvd.I get this strange message from VMware player. Even when I instead use the iso image itself instead of the dvd,I get the same message.
[image]

Iso contents:
[image]

[E drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6G8A.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please make sure, you have selected appropriate DVD Drive on "Edit Virtual Machine Settings".

   [image]
2. Reboot the Virtual Machine and press Esc to select Booting device *CD-ROM Drive* as the first boot priority.

   [image]

Comment: I have changed the priority to CD-ROM and have selected the drive but still I get the same message.

Comment: If the above actions are correct, there is possibilities of corrupted installation media or corrupted download ISO. If the OS is burned properly to disc, you should be able to boot that from any physical laptop or computer. If it boot properly,disc is burned successfully. Once you ensure that, please share "virtual machine settings" screen-capture.

Comment: It was indeed a corrupted iso